# Is it possible use react-codemirror2 with formik?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, react-codemirror

I have a project and I use Formik and react-codemirror2, I want control the onChange in Formik but the onChange in codemirror2 don't have event...and i dont't know how to use... 
let me explain better :
i have a formink:

```
<Formik
   enableReinitialize
   onSubmit={values => 
       {this.submitFormDefinition(values)}}
       initialValues={this.state}
 >
  {({ handleSubmit }) => (
    <div>
      <Form
         onSubmit={handleSubmit}
         autoComplete="off"
         onChange={event => {
            this.handleChange(event)
          }}
      >
          <Field
            component={CustomInputComponent}
                    name="name"
                    id="id"
                    multiline
          />

        </Form>
    </div>
   )}
```

where I have my function  handleChange:

```
handleChange = event => {console.log('change') ....}
```

an where the CustomInputComponent is my codemirror2 component:

```
  const CustomInputComponent = ({ field, form, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <CodeMirror
      id={props.id}
      name={props.name}
      value={this.state.value}
      options={{
        mode: 'javascript',
        theme: 'default',
        lineNumbers: true,
      }}
      {...props}
      onBeforeChange={(editor, data, value) => {
        console.log({ value })
        this.setState({ jsonSchema: value })
      }}
      onChange={(editor, data, value) => {
        ?????????????
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

If I use another component as textField from Materia-UI it work i don't need to call on my CustomInputComponent the onChange , that is direct call by formink... because also the onChange of textField have as parameter event... but as you can see in the code the onChange of codeMirror doesn't have event...

I need to call the my handleChange and not onChange of codeMirror ... 
I tried to do something like that:

```
<CodeMirror
    onChange=form.handleChange
```

or use :

```
<CodeMirror
     onKeyUp={form.handleChange}
```

or:

```
<CodeMirror
     onKeyUp={(editor, event) => {
      form.handleChange(event)
      }}
```

but nothing works
my function handleChange is never call
How use react-codeMirror2 with Formik? is possible? how can I itercept the onChange of Formink?????

Answer (score 4):

Formik's `handleChange` method expects an HTMLInput change event, and it gets the updated value from the input. Unfortunately, you don't get that convenience if you're using CodeMirror. However, CodeMirror provides the value of the component onBeforeChange, and Formik provides a `setFieldValue` method, which lets you imperatively set a value into state. So you can do this:

```
<Formik {...whateverPropsYouSet}>
  (formikProps) => (
    <CodeMirror
      value={formikProps.values.yourDataField}
      onBeforeChange={(_editor, _data, value) => {
        formikProps.setFieldValue('yourDataField', value);
      }
    />
  )
</Formik>
```